# Error Writing Custom Loss Function (can't convert symbolic tensor to numpy array)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm looking to implement a custom loss function for my neural network using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (`scipy.stats.ks_2samp`). The code that I use is below. I've changed out my full data set for the small one defined in the code, making sure that the data is in the same format.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, callbacks
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
              [2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2],
              [1,3,5,4,2,5,6,3,2],
              [6,7,8,5,3,2,2,1,5],
              [4,1,2,8,5,6,9,4,7],
              [5,2,3,6,9,1,5,8,4],
              [7,4,1,2,5,3,6,9,8],
              [5,2,1,4,7,8,5,2,3],
              [6,9,8,5,2,3,6,1,4],
              [1,2,5,4,1,2,6,8,5]])
y = np.array([[0,0,0,1,2,5,6,3,2,1,5,2,4,8,9,6,5],
              [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,7,8,5,1,6,4,9,3,5,2],
              [0,0,0,1,9,8,7,5,6,1,2,4,2,3,6,5,0],
              [0,0,0,1,2,5,4,7,8,5,9,6,3,2,6,1,5],
              [0,0,0,4,8,5,2,3,6,5,4,2,1,8,7,5,9],
              [0,0,0,6,3,1,2,6,4,2,8,4,6,5,9,3,1],
              [0,0,0,6,2,3,5,4,1,2,0,5,7,4,1,2,3],
              [0,0,0,6,9,8,5,6,3,2,1,4,5,8,7,4,1],
              [0,0,0,2,5,6,9,5,2,3,8,9,5,9,5,6,3],
              [0,0,0,2,2,5,2,6,2,1,4,8,5,2,3,5,1]])

def KS_stat(y_true,y_pred):
    return ks_2samp(y_true,y_pred)[0]

x_train,x_valid,y_train,y_valid = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    min_delta=0.001,
    patience=20,
    restore_best_weights=True
    )
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=10, activation='relu',input_shape=[9]),
    layers.Dropout(rate=0.3),
    layers.Dense(units=17)
    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=KS_stat, run_eagerly=False)
history = model.fit(
    x_train,y_train,
    validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid),
    epochs=100,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks = [early_stopping]
    )
history_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
plot = history_df.loc[5:,['loss','val_loss']].plot(
    title='Accuracy vs. Epoch',
    xlabel='Epochs',
    ylabel='loss')
fig = plot.get_figure()

predict_x = np.array([[9,0,7,5,6,4,3,2,5]])
print(model.predict(predict_x))
```

From what I understand, keras makes a symbolic tensor variable during `model.fit`. The function ks_2samp takes an array as the input. Is it possible for me to implement this directly? I was also thinking that I could try making the KS test using built-in Tensorflow functions.

Comment: You need to implement the loss using only tensorflow functions, in order for autograd to be able to compute gradients.